# how do I define a member of the linked list?

Tags: .net, c++, templates

[`LinkedList<T>` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx):
I want each member to be a struct containing an
[`IPAddress` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s128tyf6.aspx) and an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Foo {
  IPAddress a;
  int dummy;
};

int main() {
  LinkedList<Foo> list;
}
```

Comment: Does the managed linked list operate only on managed types?  And don't you need to use `gcroot<>` to store a managed reference in a non-managed type?

Comment: @AndréCaron I only now realize that this is a .NET question. This answer is purely based on what I know about C++. If there are any hidden caveats in .NET I overlooked, feel free to edit that in.

Comment: I haven't done any managed/native interop in quite some time and C++ CLI has changed since then, so I'm not sure if that advice still applies.

Comment: @user494461: If this doesn't work, try using `public value struct` instead (declares a managed value type).  If you really want a native C++ object, then consider using `gcroot<>` as described in [How to: Declare Handles in Native Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f(v=vs.80).aspx).